# How to position HTML Canvas fillRect() on the far right of a browser window on varying screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Basically, I have an animation of a sqaure travelling from right to left. Since I dont know what screen size I will be using to present my work, I cannot hard code a starting x-position value (e.g sqrx = 1400) for the starting position.If the animation is played on a larger screen to what I am developing on, the browser window will be much larger therefore the animation will start in the middle of the screen.

TLDR: Set the starting X position of right to left moving animation to snap to the right edge of a browser window no matter how big/small the browser window is.

```
var canvasWidth = c.width();
var canvasHeight= c.height();

//Vars to allow buttons to work for reset functionality
var playAnimation= true;
var startButton = $("#startAnimation");
var stopButton = $("#stopAnimation");
//Start position of Square
var sqrx = 1310; 

//Animation timer
function animate(){
    sqrx--;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(sqrx,700,40,50);
    setTimeout(animate,33);
//save state when the cavnas is first drawn.
    ctx.save();
};
animate();
```

[image: Black square starts off the browser page since I am using a hardcode value that was set on a larger screen size]

Answer (score 0):

it'll be a lot easier if you can give canvas, the width and height of window so that no matter which device you use it'll get the value of window screen size :

```
var width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Give the rectangle value for its size :

```
var rect_size = 50;
```

This will make it easier for you to position the rectangle in the canvas.

```
function draw(){
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.fillRect(width - rect_size , 0 , rect_size , rect_size);
   ctx.fill();
}
draw();
```